# more than one reactive events to subset markers in Leaflet in R

Tags: r, leaflet, events, subset

I am trying to create a shiny ap in R that displays markers on a map. I have a couple of categories that I would like to subset. Currently, I can subset but the map is only reactive on a single input (ethnicity). I would like the map to be reactive no matter the input. I tried doing the following

```
  df <- eventReactive(input$Ethnicity | input$IQ, {
     daf <- subset(data_F, (Ethnicity == input$Ethnicity & IQ > as.numeric(input$IQ))) 
     subset(daf, select = c("longitude", "latitude")) 
  })
```

This unfortunately did not work. So currently I would like an Or event statement. Either a user can manipulate the slider or the pull down menu and update the markers on the map.

Currently I am failing drastically.

Here is my code as it stands.

```
ui <- fluidPage(
                selectInput(inputId = "Ethnicity", 
                            label = "Ethnicity", 
                            choices = c("Green","Purple")),

            sliderInput (inputId = "IQ",
                    label = "IQ", step = 1,
                    value = 0, min = 0, max = 200)
                    ,
  leafletOutput(outputId = "map")
)

server <- function(input, output, session){ 

  df <- eventReactive(input$Ethnicity, {
     daf <- subset(data_F, (Ethnicity == input$Ethnicity & IQ > as.numeric(input$IQ))) 
     subset(daf, select = c("longitude", "latitude")) 
  })  

  output$map <- renderLeaflet({
   leaflet () %>%
    addTiles() %>%
    addMarkers( lng = df()$longitude, lat = df()$latitude, 
        clusterOptions = markerClusterOptions())
  })
} 

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```